# Using key file as password with OpenSSL

Tags: command-line, linux-mint, openssl

I got an assignment to decrypt a binary file which is encrypted using aes. I have a 32 byte binary file which is a key for decryption. I know how to decrypt if the key is a passphrase by using

```
openssl enc -d -aes-256-cbc -in file.out
```

In this case, the key is a binary file. How do I use it?

Answer (score 10):

Add `-pass file:nameofkeyfile` to the OpenSSL command line. This causes OpenSSL to read the password/passphrase from the named file, but otherwise proceed normally.

For more details, see the man page for openssl(1) (`man 1 openssl`) and particularly its section "PASS PHRASE ARGUMENTS", and the man page for enc(1) (`man 1 enc`).

If the key file actually holds the *encryption key* (not something from which to derive the encryption key), then you want to use `-K` instead. For that, you need something like:

```
-K $(hexdump -v -e '/1 "%02X"' < nameofkeyfile)
```

in the OpenSSL command line instead of `-pass`. `hexdump` is used to transform the key file to the pure hexadecimal representation that OpenSSL wants.

Comment: -1 If the keyfile contains a newline, then this will break. The file will only be read up to the first newline.

Comment: Note that OpenSSL does not "want" hex input.  It expects the passphrase encoded in a particular way (e.g., it accepts valid UTF-8 characters).  I was misled by this answer.  Converting to hex is not necessarily bad, but strictly speaking not what openssl wants.  See the passphrase-encoding(7) man page (which may not have existed in 2013 with older versions of openssl).

Comment: By the way, the comment from @forest (not applicable after the answer was edited to add the hexdump) is a hint to other failures.  Specifically, binary represenation of the passphrase is not a valid encoding and not a good choice for a passphrase.  Here's an example where a 0x00 byte caused someone issues: http://alexander-stoyan.blogspot.com/2013/08/error-reading-password-from-bio-resolved.html